# Making a Record Related List Button for Classic and Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-components, list-button

I have a related list button in Classic that isn't working in Lightning and we are still transitioning. We created a Lightning Action that calls a Lightning Component and leads to the same controller as the related list button. I was wondering if I can make the related list button work for Classic and Lightning.

In the past I have managed to create a button that opens a report in Classic and Lightning based on what the user is in.

{!IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed="Theme4d",
URLFOR('/lightning/r/Report/00O1B000009TgKdUAK/view?fv0=' + Case.AccountId ),
URLFOR('/00O1B000009TgKd', null, [pv0=Case.AccountId])
)}

this is the classic button.
[image]

In Lightning we have an action that calls a Lightning Component that does the same stuff as the classic button.
[image]

does anyone know if it is possible to call the Lightning Component if in Lightning or just call the class if in Classic?

I have updated the Aura component to have isURLAddressable and tried to update my list button but it is not working.

```
 <aura:component
  implements="force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable, force:hasRecordId"
  extends="c:CAE_OpportunityCustomClone"
>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
</aura:component>
```

Button:
{!IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed="Theme4d",
URLFOR('/lightning/cmp/c__CAE_CloneToDependantChild?c__id={!Opportunity.Id}&c__Object=Opportunity&c__OpportunityId={!Opportunity.Id}'),

URLFOR('/apex/CloneOpportunity?
Id={! Opportunity.Id }
&new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F{!Account.Id}
%26accid%3D{!Account.Id}%26opp3%3D{!Account.Name} -
&CF00N30000005eGbC={! Opportunity.Name }
&CF00N30000005eGbC_lkid={! Opportunity.Id}
&opp3=
&RecordTypeDevName=Defence_Child_Opportunity_Contracted_Follow_On_Contract
&ContractType=Dependent Child') )}

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is happening? Is it navigating to the component but not behaving the way you expect? Or is it behaving in some other way? One thing that isn't clear from the snippet is if or how you're processing the query parameters from the page state

Comment: @JeffKranz, I cannot save my list button. I am now trying to create a separate aura component for the isUrlAddressable. 
the list button and the lightning action should run the same code / perform the same actions. I don't think my button is right at all.

Comment: Your merge syntax is off. you've got the entire formula inside {!IF(...)}, which is fine, but then inside of that you've got additional instances of {! ... } which is unnecessary and would cause issues. once you are inside {! ... } you then only need to reference Object.Field instead of declaring {!Object.Field} every time. See the syntax in the example in my answer

Comment: @JeffKranz, I will try this! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain what I need to do and why :)

Answer (score 0):

If the lightning component has the `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface, you can link to it with a URL button in a similar manner.

Once it has this interface, the component will also have access to the PageReference so that it can retrieve any query parameters that are added to the URL and process them or assign them to attributes in the component

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation

You'd end up with something like this for your URL button

```
{!IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed="Theme4d", 
     URLFOR('/lightning/cmp/c__MyComponent?c__accountId=' + Case.AccountId ), 
     URLFOR('/apex/MyVFPageForClassic') )}
```

The important thing to note is that the component would need to be designed to handle this, it won't just allow this out of the box.

Comment: Hey Jeff! Thanks for your idea, I will try this. I already have a quick action that calls the component. Do you know if I would need to create a second lightning component that is URLaddressable or can I have one component that is both.


<aura:component
  implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId"
  extends="c:CAE_OpportunityCustomClone"
>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
</aura:component>

Comment: I have updated the Aura component to have isURLAddressable and tried to update my list button but it is not working.I posted my work above as an edit.

Comment: Just saw your edit to the question before I saw this comment- you should be able to add the interface to the same component as the quick action, but there may be behavior differences that you want to keep separate, so its really an implementation decision up to you. See my new comment on the question asking about the behavior